# Angular single page app works fine, but returns 404 when hitting any page except the main one

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, single-page-application

I have a single page web application written in Angular.

When I run it on the local machine with `ng serve`, it works fine.

When it is deployed to a bucket in AWS S3, all pages except the main page return a 404 error. In other words, the 404 error occurs when trying to load any route directly.

For example, `/` returns `200 OK` but `/terms`, `/register?lang=en`, `/store` - all of which actually load the same single-page app - return a `404 Not Found`.

Although the error code is 404, the HTML is still returned properly and most users see all pages correctly.

However, some testing tools and some mobile browsers seem to not work when the HTTP status code is 404 instead of 200.

The response headers include this:

```
x-amz-error-code →NoSuchKey
x-amz-error-message →The specified key does not exist.
x-amz-error-detail-Key →register
```

What can possibly be misconfigured that causes this error? Something in the app or something in AWS?

Comment: If you're using S3, you should specify the Error document the same as your Index document.

Comment: But the S3 docs say: `When an error occurs, Amazon S3 returns an HTML error document. If you configured your website with a custom error document, Amazon S3 returns that error document. However, some browsers display their own error message when an error occurs, ignoring the error document that Amazon S3 returns. For example, when an HTTP 404 Not Found error occurs, Google Chrome might ignore the error document that Amazon S3 returns and display its own error.` - which means there will still be a 404

Comment: As S3 is a static host, and you have an angular SPA, angular should be responsible for routing and handling errors, so you should always return the index.html file and let angular decide (on the frontend) how to handle the url.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a similar context and was able to solve it by creating a copy of index.html file, naming it **404.html**

### Update

The `404.html` file approach solved my problem when deploying the Angular app to a locally installed **Tomcat**.

Since then, I had to deploy it to an **Apache HTTP Server**. To make it work correctly on there, I had to create an `.htaccess` file with the following content and place it in the application's `src` directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^ /index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you think that's the best solution? Any community standard to achieve that?